# Regex for Username not working

Tags: java, regex

Here is my regex for validating a username:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]+([\\s.]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*){6,20}$
```

The username should be between `6-20` characters, with `space` or `period(.)` followed by a word or character.

But this regex fails for the following examples, even though the entire string length(including space is at least 6 characters):

1. joe jim
2. adam rick

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: you need to escape the '.' as well, because a '.' in a regex means 'Any character'

Comment: thanks for highlighting!

Comment: Note that you do **not** need to escape meta characters in a character class unless it's a dash `-` if it's between two characters not used in a range or a caret `^` if it's at the beginning of the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a positive lookahead to make sure there's between 6 to 20 characters inclusive:

```
^(?=.{6,20}$)[a-zA-Z0-9]+([\\s.][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$
 ^----------^
```

And you shouldn't really need the `?` for the space/period here.

Comment: I dont really want the space or period to appear more than once in between characters. Also I dont want to allow any other special characters. With this $,#, is accepted.

Comment: @root Did you test the regex? No `$` or `#` is being accepted here. Only `[a-zA-Z0-9]` and space and period are being accepted. And no consecutive space/period is accepted.

Comment: Well, I didn't replace \\s with \s and also didn't escape the period, which doing so made your regex work!! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can match your user with this.

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9\s\.]){6,20}$
```

This will probably match more than just your login.
Because this will match multiple blank spaces or periode.
You can use an other regex to mach that you login has just one periode or blank space.

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[\s\.]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: After enforcing the limit of {6,20} characters, it causes the same problem. Btw resolved it through Jerry's regex.